# the meaning of Sun-speak

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Lindsay, with *A Voyage to Arcturus,* tests the same visionary and linguistic envelopes. In the Orwellian view of language, the reduction of vocabulary to a functional and brutal *Sun*-speak is seen as a means of limiting the population's consciousness itself; pruning the gorgeous wilderness of language back to predetermined boundaries...
>
> source: Alan Moore's *Introduction to A Voyage to Arcturus*

Can you please explain the meaning of *Sun*-speak? It is nowhere to be found.

Comment: I would guess that *Sun* is a reference to a newspaper which uses a limited vocabulary. Quite which is anyone's guess, though.

Comment: Perhaps *A Voyage to Arcturus* is a novel or short story, and perhaps Sun-speak is a fictional language invented by the author and spoken by the characters in the novel? This term does not have any standard meaning in English. In George Orwell's novel *Nineteen Eighty-Four* there was a fictional language called Newspeak.

Comment: @ghostarbeiter is largely correct. I don't recall the term `Sun-speak` being  in the _Voyage_, but it has been a while since I read it. I suspect Moore coined the term to draw a parallel to Orwell's Newspeack.

Answer (score 18):

I believe Alan Moore is referring to the British tabloid newspaper *The Sun*, which is notorious for its simplified, often prejudiced, language.